# How to dequeueCell in a CCTableView with multiple custom CCTableViewCell’s?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have a CCTableView that i would like to use multiple custom CCTableViewCells, but it seems that dequeueCell treats all cells as if they were the same. The other option is to have a different cell for each row but this is not performant.

Oh and this is cocos2dx v2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually came up with a decent solution but it requires adding this member to `CCTableView`

```
CCTableViewCell *CCTableView::dequeueCellWithTag(int nTag)
{
    CCTableViewCell *cell = NULL;

    for (int i = 0, len = m_pCellsFreed->count(); i < len; i++) {
        CCTableViewCell *tempCell = (CCTableViewCell*)m_pCellsFreed->objectAtIndex(i);
        if (tempCell->getTag() == nTag) {
            cell = tempCell;
            cell->retain();
            m_pCellsFreed->removeObjectAtIndex(i);
            cell->autorelease();
            break;
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Basically you do `cell->setTag(tagId)` on your cell after you create it and then you `tableView->dequeueCellWithTag(tagId)`. Hopefully this could be built in because its pretty standard.

If anyone knows a better way i'm open to suggestions!